# Get child from parent in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm new to Entity Framework and for now I can load the parent by id.

But I want to access to the child property from my parent after I load the parent.

```
    protected void getChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JeansEntities db = new JeansEntities();
        Employe employe = db.Employes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 3);

        uxCountry.Text = //(address.Country) Its the child of Employe, but I can acces by the parent
    }
```

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I do the lines of codes of both answers and I still can access the Address child...

Comment: According to your diagram, your Employee has multiple addresses. Which one of those are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by letting the query know that you also want the Address child.  You can do this by using "eager loading."  This is done by the `Include("NavigationPropertyName")`

```
protected void getChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JeansEntities db = new JeansEntities();
    Employe employe = db.Employes.Include("Addresses")
       .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 3);

    var address = employe.Addresses.FirstOrDefault();

    if (address != null)
        uxCountry.Text = address.Country;
}
```

In order for this to work you must include a relationship between `Employe` and `Addresses` in the edm.

Comment: According to his model Employee, has multiple Addresses.

Comment: Yes the employes can have 2 Addresses or one

Comment: I have corrected my code to handle multiple addresses.  Notice the change in the include as well.  Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Include in your linq query:

```
Employe employe = db.Employes.Include(e=>e.Address).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 3);
```

Or you can use lazy evaluation if your navigation property is virtual. In this case you can use `var address = employe.Address` when your DBContext db is not disposed, and EF get it from database for you.

**Update:** You should `#using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: What is the symptoms? Is it compile? Is it throws any exception or what?

Comment: Employe employe = db.Employes.Include(c=>c.Addresses).SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 3); Throw an exception :Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @FrankSharp This is the [`Include` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). Add `using System.Data.Entity;`